# How to Crop a image using gdscript in Godot?

Tags: image, slice, godot, gdscript

I am making a game in Godot and took a 2d Sprite sheet with lots of pictures in it and I wanted those pictures to be cropped accordingly and store them in an array so I can use them later, But the problem is that Godot has no function that crops the image acc to given Rect2 prams,

so, please Help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with sprites and you have a sprite sheet. You can configure the `Hframes` and `Vframes` of your `Sprite` node to match the rows and columns of your sprite sheet. Then specify what sprite you want using the `frame` property.

Alternatively, you can use a `CanvasItem` node (any `Control` or `Node2D`, including `Sprite`) and use `draw_texture_rect` to draw only a portion of a texture on it.

*Other options include a custom shader, and using C# to manipulate images. However, assuming you want sprites, the above should suffice.*

Answer (score -1):

func _ready():
yield(VisualServer, "frame_post_draw")
var img = get_viewport().get_texture().get_data()
img.flip_y()
img.crop(200, 200)
img.save_png("Ax_Node2.png")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).